# not getting everything in a MacOS webview screenshot

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, screenshot

wI am trying to capture a screenshot of a cocoa webview using this code:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRepRight = [[webView mainFrame].frameView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:cacheRect];

[[[webView mainFrame].frameView  documentView] layout];

[[webView mainFrame].frameView cacheDisplayInRect:cacheRect toBitmapImageRep:bitmapRepRight];

return [bitmapRepRight CGImage];
```

This code is called from the - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame function.

I am only getting the background of the page but no text neither images.

If I call it using [self performSelector:@selector(addPagesToCache) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];   then it works but this is not a clean way at all.

What could be the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you found anything yet ? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I am still using my workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

If your webview is visible (in a window), you could use CGWindowListCreateImage to take a partial image of the window. This is also a workaround, not a perfect solution.